# FOSJsRoutingBundle - The route "xxx" does not exist

Tags: ajax, symfony, nginx

I'm using fosJsRouting to generate routes for my ajax calls.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 + nginx + php 7

```
app/Kernel.php
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
            );
```

And the config...

```
app/config/config.yml
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

This is the bundle routing

```
pablo_user_getonline:
    path:     user/getonline
    defaults: { _controller: pabloUserBundle:User:getonline }
    methods:  [POST,GET]
    options: { expose: true }
```

The Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "pablo_user_getonline",
            method: "POST",
            data:[],
            success: function (result) {

                $('#delete-progress').addClass('hidden');

                if(result.data == 1)
                {
                    alert("Status changed");
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#message-danger').removeClass('hidden');

                    $('#user-message-danger').text(result.message);
                }
            }}).fail(function(){
            alert('ERROR');
        });
});
```

And the layout...

```
{% block javascripts %}
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/pablouser/js/bootbox.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/pablouser/js/set-online.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/pablouser/js/get-online.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/pablouser/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When i run app/console fos:js-routing:debug get this:

```
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+------+------------------------------+
| Name                         | Method      | Scheme | Host | Path                         |
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+------+------------------------------+
| pablo_user_getonline         | POST|GET    | ANY    | ANY  | /user/getonline              |
| pablo_user_setonline         | POST        | ANY    | ANY  | /user/setonline              |
| pablo_publication_index      | ANY         | ANY    | ANY  | /publication/index           |
| pablo_publication_delete     | POST|DELETE | ANY    | ANY  | /publication/delete/{id}     |
| pablo_publication_seoprocess | POST        | ANY    | ANY  | /publication/seoprocess/{id} |
| get_domain_info_ajax         | POST        | ANY    | ANY  | /getAjaxDomainInfo           |
| register_domain              | POST        | ANY    | ANY  | /registerDomain              |
+------------------------------+-------------+--------+------+------------------------------+
```

Anyone of this routes are found when Routing.generate.

I've been looking around to find a solution so i tried to:

- set options to expose = true
- Add this routes to expose into the app/config/config.yml
- Symfony cache is clear
- Assets are all installed.

Comment: Try in console:

`Routing.generate('route_name', /* your params */)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate you url you should use `Routing.generate(path, parameters)`

```
url: Routing.generate("pablo_user_getonline"),
```

You should also add

```
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

as defined [here in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)